# Mongodb C++ driver, failure at cleanup

Tags: c++, mongodb

I have a small program that tries to connect to mongodb and check how many objects it would receive if I could hope to receive objects.  In the event, I can't even get a count of objects, and I segfault on cleanup even if I do nothing but connect.

I'm using the GlobalInstance object to maintain my connection and clean up for me at exit.  This function I call from main.  The program doesn't really do anything else yet.

Any suggestions on what I'm doing wrong that I segfault?  Presumably this is related to not being able to call connection->count()?

Many thanks for any pointers.

```
int foo() {
mongo::client::Options options;
options.setSSLMode(mongo::client::Options::kSSLRequired);
mongo::client::GlobalInstance mongo_connection(options);
mongo::DBClientBase* connection;
if (!mongo_connection.status().isOK()) {
    cout << "Mongo connection not established: "
     << mongo_connection.status() << endl;
}
try {
    mongo::DBClientConnection c(true);
    string error;
    ostringstream mongo_url;
    mongo_url << "mongodb://" << db_username << ":" << db_password << "@"
          << db_host << ":" << db_port << "/" << db_name;
    const mongo::ConnectionString conn_string =
    mongo::ConnectionString::parse(mongo_url.str(), error);
    if (!conn_string.isValid()) {
    cout << "Bad connection string: " << error << endl;
    }
    // Reality check.  Passes.
    cout << "user=" << conn_string.getUser() << endl;
    cout << "pass=" << conn_string.getPassword() << endl;
    cout << "db=  " << conn_string.getDatabase() << endl;
    const auto servers = conn_string.getServers();
    for (const auto& server : servers) {
    cout << "serv=" << server << endl;
    }
    cout << "type=" << conn_string.type() << endl;
    // End reality check.
    connection = conn_string.connect(error);
        cout << "error says: " << error << endl;       // Is empty.
        cout << "conn=" << connection << endl;    // Not zero.
    std::cout << "connected ok" << std::endl;
    cout << connection->getConnectionId() << endl;  // Prints "1".

    // This returns an error 13, not authorized, if I included it.
    //cout << "count: " << connection->count("focus_groups") << endl;
} catch( const mongo::DBException &e ) {
    std::cout << "caught " << e.what() << std::endl;
}
cout << "----------------------------------------------------------------------" << endl;
return 0;
}

/*
  Note that I can do this in the mongo shell with no problem:

  jeff@siegfried:~ $ mongo my_host:27017/my_db --ssl -u my_user -p
  MongoDB shell version: 2.6.3
  Enter password:
  connecting to: my_host:27017/my_db
  > db.focus_groups.count()
  26
  >
*/
```

I am running on 64 bit ubuntu 15.04 and compiling with clang 3.6.0.  Boost is 1.55 installed via apt-get.  The legacy mongo C++ driver I compiled and installed from git at HEAD (861699d116627d63e1c914384a66e4e3ea7c23bc) with ssl support.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This turned out to be a confluence of several things, but at least these two:

- When I compiled the legacy driver, the default mode is C++03, which is not binary compatible with C++11 or C++14.
- The driver is sensitive to differences in the version of boost with which it and the client using it are compiled.

An extensive thread appears [here](https://groups.google.com/forum/#!topic/mongodb-user/_k6DTB8I5ng).